# Keyboard gets stuck in ios 13 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I have been trying to make my project work with the new Xcode 11. Everything works smoothly, except on several occasions when I run my app on the simulator (iPhone 11 Pro Max), the app freezes after I click on EditTexts. This happens after a few times I have used the app. If I clear the simulator memory and restart everything works normally.

I created a view controller with just the EditText and am able to replicate the simulator freezing. Sometimes it freezes before launching the soft keypad, sometimes after it has been displayed. I am still able to kill the app and rerun it through Xcode but it freezes every time unless I do hardware reset on simulator.

I am just concerned if this would happen on the device too? Has anyone faced this?

Edit: Just to add. When this happens, I try to use the messaging app and the same thing happens there.

Comment: Check whether any memory drain is happening while editing

Comment: It would be better if you attach a link to your example project, but it's really weird thing that has happened to you.

Comment: iOS 13 is now available for your phone so why not install it and find out?

Comment: what a foolish thing, I was trying to change my code and trying to detect any issue in code. Thanks you saved a lot more time.

Answer (score 25):

Same problem on Xcode 11.0 and simulator with iOS 13/iPhone 11.

For me, the workaround of disable "automatically paste" don't work.

The only way is to restart simulator.

This thread is open on Apple Forum [https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122972]

Comment: Stupid apple! It's still in 11.4.1.

Answer (score 17):

The only fortunate solutions is to restart the simulator.

Comment: it's the real solution

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. Apparently it's a bug on the Simulator. Hopefully it will be solved soon, but until then, you can fix by unchecking the pasteboard option.

> Simulator -> Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard.

From this helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175221/xcode-11-simulator-wont-respond/58289859#58289859).

Answer (score 10):

This is happening to me as well. This is a bug with the current release of Simulator.

Answer (score 9):

When i click on textfield, app freeze and stop working. This problem still exists on Xcode 11.1 The solution is:

"Hardware -> Restart"

Then running normally. Try this.

Answer (score 5):

Force quit the simulator and restart again works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Same happens even in built-in apps on iOS 13 Simulator in the moment when you about to start typing :facepalm:  Initially I thought that happened because I included new framework and had no clues what's going on but then found this :)

Answer (score 3):

Please do not change your code it's not your code issue, its simulator bug.... So try to restart the simulator or stop the application and run again.

It will work fine on your device.

Answer (score 3):

On **Mac Catalina** with **Xcode 11.4** I tried this:

From simulator, toolbar choose **I/O** then **Keyboard** then **Toggle Software Keyboard**

Or

Simply hit **Command + K** while cursor placed in text Field.

Answer (score 1):

Also have the same problem. When I restarted the simulator after it got stuck it haven't happened again. Seems like it is a simulator bug and not an app issue - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122972

Answer (score 1):

Its happening when pickerView appears as well, unfortunately have to restart simultor again.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If your are working on the iOS Simulator than simpley *Restart your simulator* & * Kill the Metro *
and run the react-native run-ios again.