# Xcode 11 - Simulator won't respond

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

Ever since I updated to Xcode 11, the simulator freezes intermittently. Specially when the keyboard is brought to focus. I don't think it has anything to do with memory or any hardware specs of my Mac since it does not crashes, just doesn't respond to any events.

The only solution so far is to rebuild again and again the app until the touch on the textfield magically responds again.

Has anyone faced the same problem? Any ideias on what might be causing it?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having an issue that sounds potentially related.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194400/simulator-freezes-at-animation-blocks-after-swift-5-xcode-11-update

Comment: Now its even more intriguing! Glad to know I'm not alone in this, haha.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122972) in Apple's developer forum it's a bug in the simulator. A workaround is to disable to Pasteboard sync in the simulator. Uncheck the option in Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you. I hope they fix the bug soon.

Comment: Having a similar issue with Xcode 11.4 GA, Not related to Textfield or Keyboard usage. Happens randomly after a build to either device or the simulator. App is frozen after launch.

Comment: It's 2022 and I just encountered this issue, using Xcode 13.4.1 on an M1 MacBook Pro. It seems like the pasteboard syncing gets stuck in a loop. I'm guessing this is very difficult to replicate, which is why the issue still exists.