# Simulator Freezes at Animation Blocks After Swift 5 / Xcode 11 Update

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, uiviewanimation, xcode11

I updated my project to Swift 5 in Xcode 11 and now the program freezes at my animation blocks in the iPhone 11 simulator. When I set a breakpoint after the animation it never hits it.  Restarting Xcode and the Simulator did not solve the issue.  If I run the program on a device it works fine.

Any ideas about what's going on?  Maybe a memory issue?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn], animations: {

    self.introTextView.transform = self.introTextView.transform.translatedBy(x: 200, y: 0)
})
```

Comment: That is the exact code that runs where the program just stops.  It worked perfectly fine before the update.  If I take out this animation there's another animation block after it and it would just stop right there at the next one.

Comment: I understand your point @matt.  Thanks for trying to help.  I'm 99% sure I've got a corner case because I don't see anyone else bringing up this issue now or when Xcode 11 was in beta.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's a bug on the Simulator. Hopefully it will be solved soon, but until then, you can fix by unchecking the pasteboard option.

> Simulator -> Edit -> Automatically Sync Pasteboard.

From this helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175221/xcode-11-simulator-wont-respond/58289859#58289859).

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my computer everything now seems to be working fine.  If that changes I will report back in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

UPDATE: Unfortunately it's a temporary fix.  After a while, the simulator freeze issue starts again and I need to restart to get it working properly.

Additional UPDATE: After updating to the newest version of Xcode the issue went away.

Comment: Hi @Ben sorry to hear about this; it sounds like maybe it's a simulator bug. I have two suggestions: (1) update to a newer version of Xcode, and (2) if the problem persists, try to reproduce it in a small project and file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Thanks @matt.  I'm using the latest version of Xcode (non beta) at the moment (11.0 - 11A420a).  Thanks for the encouragement to file a bug report.

Comment: Well, that is not the latest non beta version; 11.1 is. And you might also try 11.2 beta which is also out. Of course I don't promise either of them fixes this, but there is no point filing the bug if they do. :)

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks!